# What is the probability that the number of tosses is not more than 4 given the following conditions?

Tags: probability

> An unbiased coin is tossed until it shows up the same face in two consecutive throws.What is the probability that the number of tosses is not more than 4?

My approach:

When $2$ coins are tosses:

A:

Coin is tossed until it shows the same face i.e (H,T),(T,H),(H,H) or (T,T)=2 possible outcomes because it will Stop hewn it see a HH or TT

P(A)=$2$/$4$=$1$/$2$

When $3$ coins are tosses:

B:

Coin is tossed until it shows the same face i.e (H,T,H),(T,H,T),(H,H,T) or (T,T,H) or (H,H,H) or (T,T,T)=2 possible outcomes because it will Stop hewn it see a HHT or TTH.

P(B)=$2$/$8$=1/4

When $4$ coins are tosses:

C:

Coin is tossed until it shows the same face i.e (H,T,H,T),(T,H,T,H) only

P(C)=1/8

On Adding, I will get $7$/$8$

> Can anyone give me Hint what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not taking into account that it can happen on later throws (but before or on the 4th throw). For example the flips  T,H,H means that 2 heads appear one after another and in under 4 throws, you haven't counted this possibility.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are not taking 4 throws into account, only 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perhaps simpler way to view your problem is to ask what is the probability that the 2nd throw equals the first, which is $1/2$, and then with probability $1/2$ they are different and you make a third throw, which also has probability $1/2$ to equal the 2nd throw, and then similarly for the fourth throw. This gives $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8$ as your answer.

Another way to view it is to ask what is the probability it takes more than 4 throws? This means you either start with heads or tails and then the next 3 coin flips must be alternating. This has probability $(1/2)^3 = 1/8$.